# Vuetify group of checkboxes returns all true

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an issue with all my checkboxes always being true.
I've tried using the "false-value" attribute, but to no help.

I also have a default input checkbox, which is functioning properly.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      straps: [],
      checkedColors: [],
      checkedSkins: [],
      checkedTypes: [],
      filterings: [{
          title: "Farver",
          filters: [{
              title: "Grøn",
              value: "grøn",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Rød",
              value: "rød",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Gul",
              value: "yellow",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Lilla",
              value: "lilla",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Blå",
              value: "blå",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Grå",
              value: "grå",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Sort",
              value: "sort",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Hvid",
              value: "hvid",
              model: "checkedColors"
            },
            {
              title: "Brun",
              value: "brun",
              model: "checkedColors"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Materialer",
          filters: [{
              title: "Alligator",
              value: "alligator",
              model: "checkedSkins"
            },
            {
              title: "Struds",
              value: "ostridge",
              model: "checkedSkins"
            },
            {
              title: "Teju firben",
              value: "teju",
              model: "checkedSkins"
            },
            {
              title: "Haj",
              value: "shark",
              model: "checkedSkins"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Remme til",
          filters: [{
              title: "Universal",
              value: "universal",
              model: "checkedTypes"
            },
            {
              title: "Audemars Piguet",
              value: "ap",
              model: "checkedTypes"
            },
            {
              title: "Jaeger LeCoultre",
              value: "jlc",
              model: "checkedTypes"
            },
            {
              title: "Rolex",
              value: "rolex",
              model: "checkedTypes"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredStraps() {
      var straps = this.straps;

      if (this.search !== null) {
        var straps = this.searchItems.filter(strap => {
          if (!this.search) return this.searchItems;
          return (
            strap.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.skin.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
            strap.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
          );
        });
      }

      if (this.checkedSkins.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          return this.checkedSkins.includes(strap.skin.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
      if (this.checkedTypes.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          return this.checkedTypes.includes(strap.type.toLowerCase());
        });
      }

      if (this.sort == "newest") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
      }
      if (this.sort == "priceasc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);
      }
      if (this.sort == "pricedesc") {
        return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price);
      } else {
        return straps;
      }
    },
       getStraps() {
  db.collection("straps")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const straps = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const data = {
          id: doc.id,
          title:
            doc
              .data()
              .type.charAt(0)
              .toUpperCase() +
            doc.data().type.slice(1) +
            " RIOS1931 " +
            doc
              .data()
              .title.charAt(0)
              .toUpperCase() +
            doc.data().title.slice(1) +
            " Urrem i " +
            doc
              .data()
              .skin.charAt(0)
              .toUpperCase() +
            doc.data().skin.slice(1),
          price: doc.data().price,
          skin: doc.data().skin,
          type: doc.data().type,
          imgs: doc.data().imgs[0].url,
          colors: doc.data().colors,
          date: doc
            .data()
            .date.toString()
            .slice(0, 15)
        };
        straps.push(data);
      });
      this.straps = straps;
    });
},
  }
```

```html
<v-layout>
  <v-flex sm3 md2 class="hidden-xs-only text-xs-left">
    <p class="pl-4"><strong>Sortering</strong></p>
    <v-expansion-panel class="elevation-0">
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="filtering in filterings" :key="filtering.title">
        <div slot="header">{{filtering.title | capitalize}}</div>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-list>
              <input type="checkbox" value="alligator" v-model="checkedSkins">
              <label for="checker"></label>
              <v-list-tile v-for="filter in filtering.filters" :key="filter.value">
                <v-list-tile-content>
                  <v-checkbox :input-value="filter.value" :label="filter.title" v-model="filter.model" color="primary"></v-checkbox>
                </v-list-tile-content>
              </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        <div slot="header">Pris</div>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex px-2>
                <v-range-slider :min="slider[0]" :max="slider[1]" v-model="slider" thumb-label="always"></v-range-slider>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs6 pr-2>
                <v-text-field label="Fra pris" v-model="slider[0]" class="mt-0" hide-details single-line type="number"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex xs6 pl-2>
                <v-text-field label="Til pris" v-model="slider[1]" class="mt-0" hide-details single-line type="number"></v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-flex>

</v-layout>
```

As mentioned the default input works as intended, but the vuetify checkboxes are all returning true for some reason, and they won't work, even though they have the same attribute values in the front-end.

Comment: A little note:
This started happening after I added ":input-value="filter.value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store checked objects as strings from `filter.value` property so you have 2 issues in your code(second one is related to your question):

1. You have incorrect value in your `v-model` directive. You bind `filter.model` variable to `v-model` **not its stored array name**, to fix this you should pass to `v-model` something like this `$data[filter.model]` to bind array from `data` as model dynamically.
2. You use `input-value` binding incorrectly. `input-value` is related to `v-model` value(see `v-checkbox` source code, it's overriding of default model), you don't need to change this value. So you need to pass `filter.value` to `value` attribute instead.

Result:

```
<v-checkbox :value="filter.value" :label="filter.title" v-model="$data[filter.model]" color="primary"></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, been looking for a solution to it for a while, and just ended up doing the other thing instead.

I think I've come closer to the answer of filtering the colors with:
      if (this.checkedColors.length > 0) {
        straps = straps.filter(strap => {
          strap.colors.filter(color => {
            return this.checkedColors.includes(color.title.toLowerCase());
          });
        });
      }

Comment: @Fred I don't see any `straps` definition and its structure in your code above

Comment: I just added the straps data and the method for a better understanding.

the output of the straps is: https://i.imgur.com/HIEBgqW.png

Comment: My bad this was for another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818032/find-match-in-two-arrays