# Find match in two arrays

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

***Update***
Got the answer:

```js
if (this.checkedColors.length > 0) {
  straps = straps.filter(strap => {
    return strap.colors.find(color => {
      return this.checkedColors.includes(color.title.toLowerCase());
    });
  });
}
```

I have two arrays, where I need to return products that match the checkbox value.

I've created a screen recording to display how this works: http://recordit.co/EddLjeqM7i

My code is the following:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    checkedColors: [],
    filterings: [{
        title: "Farver",
        filters: [{
            title: "Grøn",
            value: "grøn"
          },
          {
            title: "Rød",
            value: "rød"
          },
          {
            title: "Gul",
            value: "yellow"
          },
          {
            title: "Lilla",
            value: "lilla"
          },
          {
            title: "Blå",
            value: "blå"
          },
          {
            title: "Grå",
            value: "grå"
          },
          {
            title: "Sort",
            value: "sort"
          },
          {
            title: "Hvid",
            value: "hvid"
          },
          {
            title: "Brun",
            value: "brun"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
    computed: {
filteredStraps() {
  var straps = this.straps;

  if (this.search !== null) {
    var straps = this.searchItems.filter(strap => {
      if (!this.search) return this.searchItems;
      return (
        strap.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        strap.skin.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
        strap.type.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
  }

  if (this.checkedSkins.length > 0) {
    straps = straps.filter(strap => {
      return this.checkedSkins.includes(strap.skin.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
  if (this.checkedTypes.length > 0) {
    straps = straps.filter(strap => {
      return this.checkedTypes.includes(strap.type.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
  if (this.checkedColors.length > 0) {
    straps = straps.filter(strap => {
      return this.checkedColors.includes(strap.colors.toLowerCase());
    });
  }

  if (this.sort == "newest") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
  }
  if (this.sort == "priceasc") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price);
  }
  if (this.sort == "pricedesc") {
    return straps.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price);
  } else {
    return straps;
  }
}
  },
```

```html
<v-expansion-panel class="elevation-0">
  <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="filtering in filterings.slice(0, 1)" :key="filtering.title">
    <div slot="header">{{filtering.title | capitalize}}</div>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile v-for="filter in filtering.filters" :key="filter.value">
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-checkbox :value="filter.value" :label="filter.title" v-model="checkedColors" color="primary"></v-checkbox>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</v-expansion-panel>
```

The straps array is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bHJt.png

I'll need the function to be computed in order to match the other filtering and sorting methods, to return the straps correctly.

I have two other methods that are working, but they didn't require looping through an array to find a match for the value or values I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Fred, it's not clear to me exactly what you want to accomplish. Could you maybe show an example of what you are trying to make this function return? Using either the code snippets or (even better) a simpler example with just a few elements in both arrays.

Comment: @StephenThomas I've created a screen recording to display how this works: http://recordit.co/EddLjeqM7i